# switch a Button and Get a different at the Bottom

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio, button, android-activity

I'm new on android studio and I'm working on a small app just to practice myself and improve my knowledge. So I have 3 buttons like here 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0iXT.png]
 My question is when I switch a button to another how can I do to keep the same toolbar and just change the activity in bottom. kind of like that 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQSrC.png]
I have been thinking creating a new activity for each button but I'm not getting the same result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post CODE - another hint: CROP your images

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and either crop or scale your images down. It'll make the question much easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks for your attention but I already got answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Fragment that describes what you want to do in each pane. For example,

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ButtonOneFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container != null) {
            container.removeAllViews();
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_one_fragment, container, false);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

In your `MainActivity`, or in whichever class controls the  the tabs, call a fragment transaction whenever the selected tab changes:

```
// For AppCompat use getSupportFragmentManager
Fragment fragment = new DefaultFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

if (selectedPane == R.id.buttonOne) {
    fragment = new ButtonOneFragment();
} else if (selectedPane == R.id.buttonTwo) {
    fragment = new ButtonTwoFragment();
} else if (selectedPane == R.id.buttonThree) {
    fragment = new ButtonThreeFragment();
}

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
```

Comment: Oooooh Thanks I got it.